# How to implement a real-time performance view for core image filter

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter, glkview

I would like to implement a real-time performance view for displaying core image filter output. Form the documentation of Apple, It seem that I should use a GPU based context for drawing.

There are some term I am confused. `EAGLContext`, `CIContext`, `GLKView`. What are these things? Also, should I use `EAGLContext` to create `CGImage` from `CIImage` and set it to `UIImageView` or using the `GLKView`. What are the difference of these two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your image on the GPU by avoiding `UIImageView` and using the OpenGL view, `GLKView`. To get that working with CoreImage, you need to create a `CIContext` with a EAGL context:

```
let eaglContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)

lazy var ciContext: CIContext =
{
    [unowned self] in

    return CIContext(EAGLContext: self.eaglContext,
        options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()])
}()
```

The context of your `GLKView` should be the same `eaglContext`, it also needs a delegate that conforms to `GLKViewDelegate`.

To display an image, invalidate the display with `setNeedsDisplay()`. This will call `glkView(:drawInRect:)` on the delegate and it's in here you use the Core Image context to draw the image to the `GLKView`:

```
    ciContext.drawImage(image,
        inRect: targetRect,
        fromRect: image.extent)
```

Where `image` is the `CIImage` to display.

If all that sounds like too much effort, I've done the work for you, check out my [CoreImageHelpers](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CoreImageHelpers) repo.

Simon

Comment: Would using Core Animation of the GLKView have bad performance as the underlying image data is moving between CPU and GPU?

Comment: It may well impact performance. What are you doing with Core Animation - is it possible to achieve the same effect with Core Image?

Comment: I would like to fade in and fade out the view which rendering the CIImage.

Comment: Well, you can do that with a CIFilter and animate the property in a CADisplayLink :)

Comment: Great, `CADisplayLink` is what I am looking for. Thanks!